# View combining 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies if this has already been asked, I tried searching but didn't quite know what for!

The scenario I have is as follows:

- Table A - Holds an ID, Latitude and Longitude.
- Table B - Holds information regarding a company, as well as latitude and longitude.

I need to create a view that will hold an entry of every entry in Table B, using data from Table A to find the distance between the two places.

So for example:

Table A holds

```
id  lat  long
1   20   20
```

Table B holds

```
id  name lat long
1   A    21  20
2   B    20  21
```

And I need an output along the lines of

```
tableAid  tableBid  tableAName  distanceBetween
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: What function do you want to use for distance?  Or is that your question?

Comment: Is there a join condition in this question or do you want the distances calculated between all locations in Table A to all location in Table B?

Comment: please put some values in the expected result

Comment: I already have SQL expression that will use both tables lat and long to create the distance between. No join conditions, just want distances calculated for all entries in both tables. i.e A1B1, A1B2 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.id, b.id, b.name, SQRT(power(a.lat-b.lat, 2) +  power(a.long-b.long, 2))
from #A a
Cross Apply #B b
```

`CROSS APPLY` - will create the cross product of the tables without any join condition. I took a guess as to how you might calculate a distance between two points as well.

Comment: Why use CROSS APPLY instead of CROSS JOIN?

Comment: @RichardHansell , to be perfectly honest, there is no reason to use `cross apply` over `cross join` in this case. I used apply out of habit, having usually needed to either aggregate something or use a table valued function with the a column from the first table as a parameter.